# Thread workers and epoll

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I'm trying to implement a server that deals with many tcp connections, from 100 - 1000 connections/day based on the time of the day. after reading a lot about the c10k problem with thread per connection and using epoll only I decided to use both as a pool of threads and the main will act as a dispatcher, so each new connection will be assigned to a thread.

I have a number of questions that I can't find answers anywhere else. 
Is the following thread safe? Do I need to lock before adding the new fd?

```
int main ()
{
    while(i < number_threads)
      {         
        pthread_create( &id , NULL ,  worker , (void*) epoll_fd[i]);
        i++;
      }


//is it ok to add the new_sock for the epoll_fd[i] so the thread can pick it up
int y = 0;
    while(1) {
        new_sock = accept(...);
           if (epoll_ctl(epoll_fd[y], EPOLL_CTL_ADD, new_sock, &ev) < 0)
            {
                print error; 
            }
    y++;
    if (y == number_threads)
    y = 0;
    }

}



void *worker(void *epfd)
{
epoll_wait //start waiting for event
}
```

Comment: 1000 connections per day? Are you targeting a slide rule?

Comment: read the C tag as C++, redacted my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this:

```
pthread_create( &id , NULL ,  worker , (void*) epoll_fd + i);
```

and in the thread function, this:

```
void *worker(void *vp_epfd) {
  int *p_epfd = (int*) vp_epfd;
```

then it should work, and be thread-safe, assuming that you check for updates in `*p_epfd` in correct places.

Comment: Thanks, didn't get this part though "assuming that you check for updates in *p_epfd in correct places"

Comment: this is exactly what I was thinking about, so if it's thread safe, does that really metter? if yes then I have no idea how to implement it.

Comment: if you use the indirection `*p_epfd` to access the descriptor you should be fine